# How can I trigger an error on transaction commit?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I develop [a library that implements transactions in Postgresql](https://github.com/golergka/pg-tx), and at my job we had a weird bug in production with it, when transaction failed not on one of the queries itself, but on `COMMIT`, because of something failing in the triggers. Apparently, my library didn't handle this situation the right way.

Obviously, I wanted to replicate this bug in my test suit for the library, but I don't want to bring in all the complicated setup. All the behaviour I need, is that Postgresql has to return an error not to any of the queries inside transaction, but when you try to `COMMIT` it. What's the minimal and stable way to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use deferred constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE tst(x int CONSTRAINT test_me UNIQUE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);

begin;

insert into tst values(1);

insert into tst values(1);  -- Note: no error at this point

commit;
```

The COMMIT fails with:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_me"
DÉTAIL : Key (x)=(1) already exists.
```

Comment: Thanks, it matched what I wanted to do perfectly! https://github.com/golergka/pg-tx/blob/master/src/index.test.ts#L146-L150

Answer (score 0):

do a search for "assert"

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/192583)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).